# Create pandas column based on two conditional statements using .shift()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of user events, ordered by user_id and datetime ascending. I want to calculate the time difference between events based per-user, and I want null values for every users first event record in `df['tdelta']`. The following is fast, but doesn't nullify entries if user_id changes.

```
df['tdelta'] = df['time'] - df['time'].shift()
```

This is my current solution, but it's too slow.

```
def get_tdelta(df, tdelta_column="tdelta"):
    df[tdelta_column] = np.NaN
    df[tdelta_column] = df[tdelta_column].astype('datetime64[ns]')
    for cid, pid, ct, pt, idx in zip(df['user_id'], df['user_id'].shift(), df['time'], df['time'].shift(), df.index):
        if cid==pid:
            df.loc[idx, tdelta_column] = ct - pt
        else:
            pass
    return event_dataframe

event_df = get_tdelta(event_df)
```

I imagine there's a fast solution similar to the following, but I'm a little stuck on how to accomplish it. I've added the error I get for the following code, and I understand why I'm getting it, but I'm just looking for a faster way to accomplish it

```
df['tdelta'] = df['time'] - df['time'].shift() if (df['user_id'] == df['user_id'].shift()) else np.NaN
```

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Here's a demo before and after dataframe to visualize:

```
data = {'user_id' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        'event_id' : [2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3],
        'time' : ['2020-02-27 12:31:00', '2020-02-27 12:32:00', '2020-02-27 12:32:30', '2020-02-27 02:22:00', '2020-02-27 02:27:00', '2020-03-01 02:39:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.time = df.time.astype('datetime64[ns]')

    user_id event_id    time                   
0   1       2           2020-02-27 12:31:00    
1   1       2           2020-02-27 12:32:00     
2   1       3           2020-02-27 12:32:30     
3   2       2           2020-02-27 02:22:00     
4   2       3           2020-02-27 02:27:00     
5   2       3           2020-03-01 02:39:00
```

```
data = {'user_id' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        'event_id' : [2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3],
        'time' : ['2020-02-27 12:31:00', '2020-02-27 12:32:00', '2020-02-27 12:32:30', '2020-02-27 02:22:00', '2020-02-27 02:27:00', '2020-03-01 02:39:00'],
        'tdelta' : ['NaT', '0 days 00:01:00', '0 days 00:00:30', 'NaT', '0 days 00:05:00', '3 days 00:12:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.time = df.time.astype('datetime64[ns]')

    user_id event_id    time                    tdelta
0   1       2           2020-02-27 12:31:00     NaT
1   1       2           2020-02-27 12:32:00     0 days 00:01:00
2   1       3           2020-02-27 12:32:30     0 days 00:00:30
3   2       2           2020-02-27 02:22:00     NaT
4   2       3           2020-02-27 02:27:00     0 days 00:05:00
5   2       3           2020-03-01 02:39:00     3 days 00:12:00
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, please include an example of your dataframe so others can work on it

Comment: @Gorlomi Sorry! I added demo dataframes for visualization.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the time delta between events for each user, group by the `user_id` and apply the shift-subtraction on the grouped data frame.

Afterwards, clean up the result by dropping `user_id` from the index & assign back to the original data frame as a new column. The first events for each user_id will be `null (NaN)` by default.

```
df['tdelta'] = df.groupby('user_id') \
  .apply(lambda x: x.time - x.time.shift()) \
  .reset_index(level='user_id', drop=True)
```